# Getting Error No Module found after deploying my DRF profject on Vercel

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, deployment, vercel

i'm trying to deploy my django rest framework to vercel free tier and during the deployment to show deployed successful witth the ready been ready, but when i open the link it return the following

```
This Serverless Function has crashed.

Your connection is working correctly.

Vercel is working correctly.

500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED
ID: cdg1::525rm-1695080572313-5e091aaaa7b6

If you are a visitor, contact the website owner or try again later.
If you are the owner, learn how to fix the error and check the logs.
```

and when i open the logs i see these error  message

`[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'vc__handler__python': No module named 'django' Traceback (most recent call last):`

please can anyone help out

Comment: Can you show me the folder structure inside your app?

Comment: the structure is from project folder(containing wsgi, settings , urls files etc then in the folder are  my app folders